# Read data from GCS and load into CLOUD SQL

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am new in GCP as well as Python.

I am trying to read csv files which is present in google cloud storage and write to data into cloud sql table using Python.Can anyone help on that.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advancs

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't read and load the data if you haven't update/cleaning to perform on data. You can use the [Cloud SQL load CSV from Cloud Storage capability](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#importing_data_from_a_csv_file_in). It also work PostgreSQL (change on top on the page for this)

Do you need code example for calling a REST API in Python? (it's quite basic today, but maybe the security can annoy you!)

Comment: Actually I have to perform some transform operation that's why I want to use python in cloud functions so that it can perform etl from cloud storage to cloud sql

Comment: Understood. What's the max size of your CSV file?

Comment: Size will be some mb

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [google-cloud-storage](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/index.html) when operating with GCS. The package is basically a wrapper for GCloud's API.

Here's how you might use this library:

```
from google.cloud import storage

# create the client
path_to_service_account = "path/foo.json"
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(path_to_service_account)

# get the bucket
bucket_name = "my-bucket"
bucket = client.lookup_bucket(bucket_name)

# loop through the bucket to get the resource you want
for resource in bucket.list_blobs(prefix="dir-name/"):
    # file type doesn't need to be a csv...
    if resource.endswith("my_file.csv"):
        my_blob = bucket.get_blob(resource)
        my_blob_name = resource.split("/")[-1]
        my_blob.download_to_filename(os.path.join("save-dir", my_blob_name))

# finally, load the file from local storage:
...
```

Comment: You can. But no need to authenticate with the json. Just initiate the client with `client = storage.Client()`